# Alter table foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE credit_card ADD CONSTRAINT fk_company FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company (id);
```

I got the error *a foreign key constraint fails*, but I don't understand why. The company_id column has same type of company.id column as you can see:

Company table

```
CREATE TABLE `company` (
   `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   `description` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `currency_id` bigint NOT NULL,
   `language_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
   `address_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
   `creation_time` datetime NOT NULL,
   `modification_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `cost_center_modifiable` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `use_colleague_cost_center` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `fixed_guest_company` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `info_number` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `use_kilometric_rate` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `use_multiple_km_rate` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `email_required` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `logo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `holding_id` bigint NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`),
   KEY `fk_company_address1` (`address_id`),
   KEY `fk_company_currency1` (`currency_id`),
   KEY `company_language_FK` (`language_id`),
   KEY `company_holding_FK` (`holding_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `company_currency_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`currency_id`) REFERENCES `currency` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `company_holding_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`holding_id`) REFERENCES `holding` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `company_language_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`) REFERENCES `language` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=142 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Credit_card table

```
CREATE TABLE `credit_card` (
   `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `pan` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
   `account` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `begin_date` date NOT NULL,
   `end_date` date NOT NULL,
   `disabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `creation_time` datetime NOT NULL,
   `modification_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `company_id` bigint NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `username` (`username`),
   KEY `pan` (`pan`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_credit_card_user_ext` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `users_extension` (`username`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

Comment: 99% that `credit_card` table contains `company_id` values which are absent in `company` table...

Comment: Company_id is a new column I've just added, for now all values are null

Comment: I've tried to add the constraint in the EER diagram then generate sql but gives me the same code I've done

Comment: Is your `company` table full ?

Comment: Ohhh you right, I've added company_id not null and mysql populated the column with zeros which can't be the ids

Answer (score 0):

Dont make auto increment columns as foreign keys or unless not sure, dont reference these to autoincrement columns as it may end up making the table with foreign key issue a constraint violation if redundant entries are expected to be made in either of the tables.

Might be the case the related data is already ingested and then the table is altered

Comment: In OP's code none AI column is FK.

Comment: Check the alter command thats y its failing

Comment: ALTER TABLE creates FK in `credit_card` table using `company_id` column which is not AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: But its referring id which is autoincrement edited my answer. I mean not all cases we can keep reference to autoincrement columns but  i guess in this scenario data is already been ingested n then the table is altered